# How to inject $_SERVER variable into a Service

Tags: php, symfony, geoip

a service of my application needs to access a `$_SERVER` variable (which is provided by apache) called: `$_SERVER['GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE'];`

What are good ways to achieve this?

My current guess would be to inject the RequestStack but on the other hand I dont want to couple the complete RequestStack to this service.

Are there other ways of achieving this?

P.S.
Please don't answer me with links to bundles like https://github.com/aferrandini/Maxmind-GeoIp etc.

Comment: Which type is your service file? yml or xml?

Comment: I'm using yaml as file format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to tell your service to inject the request stack to get current request.

You can call the **request service** but it is may cause a ***ScopeWideningInjectionException*** exception because the request can change.

Your service file:

```
<?php

namespace Some\GreatBundle\ServicePath;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;

class GreatService
{
    private $request;

    public function __construct(RequestStack $requestStack)
    {
        $this->request = $requestStack->getCurrentRequest();
    }

    public function getGeoIpCountryCode()
    {
        return $this->request->server->get("GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE");
    }
}
```

YML:

```
services:
    your_great_service:
        class:     Some\GreatBundle\ServicePath\GreatService
        arguments: ["@request_stack"]
```

Comment: Maybe decouple the service with an extra geo ip service class from the request stack :)

Answer (score -2):

If I understands you, you want to use a `$_SERVER` variable in a service. I found this in the Symfony documentation:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

$request = Request::createFromGlobals();

// retrieve SERVER variables
$request->server->get('HTTP_HOST');
```

As I can see, there is no problem to achieve your variable:

```
$request->server->get('GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE');
```

[Requests and Responses in Symfony](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/http_fundamentals.html#requests-and-responses-in-symfony)

Comment: Yes, but I'm asking if there is an alternative for this, so I don't have to inject the complete RequestStack into the service.

Comment: Sure, you can also use the old $_SERVER superglobal.