# Symfony2 styled emails best practices

Tags: symfony, html-email, swiftmailer

What are the best practices to send emails from html & css? I have much mails in my projects & need the solution, that can allow me not to write all below code again & again:

```
$msg = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
    ->setSubject('Test')
    ->setFrom('noreply@example.com')
    ->setTo('user@example.com')
    ->setBody($this->renderView('MyBundle:Default:email1.text.twig'));

$this->get('mailer')->send($msg);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe my answer can help. There is a special bundle [Symfony2-MailerBundle](https://github.com/umbrella-web/Symfony2-MailerBundle) that render email body from template and allows to set up sending parameters in config file & you won't have to pass them every time you want to build & send email.

Answer (score 4):

Set that code as a function in a service. Functions are for that.

To create a service see the link below.

[How to inject $_SERVER variable into a Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24076561/how-to-inject-server-variable-into-a-service/24077841#24077841)

Note: don't forget to inject the mail service as an argument!

```
arguments: ["@mailer"]
```

After you set your service;

```
public function sendMail($data)
{
    $msg = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
        ->setSubject($data['subject'])
        ->setFrom($data['from'])
        ->setTo($data['to'])
        ->setBody($this->renderView($data['view']));

    $this->mailer->send($msg);
}
```

And you can call your service like;

```
// this code below is just for setting the data
$data = [
    'subject' => 'Hello World!', 
    'from' => 'from@address.com', 
    'to' => 'to@address.com', 
    'template' => 'blabla.html.twig'
];

// this code below is the actual code that will save you
$mailer = $this->get('my_mailer_service');
$mailer->sendMail($data);
```